# Unable to generate ssh keys for github and aws (illegal option -- C)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, github, ssh

I've been trying to set up ssh with  my github account and on following the guide on https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ and on running the command listed there : I get the following error

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
illegal option -- C
Usage: ssh-keygen [options] [key1 key2 ...]

Where `options` are:
 -b nnn         Specify key strength in bits (e.g. 1024)
 -t dsa | rsa   Choose the key type.
 -c comment     Provide the comment.
 -e file        Edit the comment/passphrase of the key.
 -p passphrase  Provide passphrase.
 -P             Assume empty passphrase.
 -?
 -h             Print this help text.
 -q             Suppress the progress indicator.
 -1             Convert a SSH 1.x key.
 -i file        Load and display information on `file'.
 -D file        Derive the public key from the private key 'file'.
 -B number      The number base for displaying key information (default 10).
 -V             Print ssh-keygen version number.
 -r file        Stir data from file to random pool.
 -F file        Dump fingerprint of file.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output of your command, I speculate you should replace `-C` with `-c` (lowercase). So try again with `-c`:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -c "your_email@example.com"
```

From the docs, `-C` is supposed to provide a new comment:

> `-C` comment
>
> Provides the new comment.

So, since your output says *Provide the comment*, I guess it should work with `-c`.

---

As alternative, you can try using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

---

It turns out that the `ssh-keygen` was actually overridden:

> I figured it out, for some reason i has another ssh-keygen binary in my /usr/local/bin, so when i used it was using that one instead of the one that comes with ubuntu in /usr/bin Deleting the extra binaries and then reinstalling Openssh-server and openssl fixed everything. Thanks!

Comment: Doing that generates a ssh2 key which doesn't work with github. 
Also, in case of aws, it autoruns this command and hence it fails midway through the process of me setting up the project with ssh.

Comment: @AdityaBalwani Using `-C` works fine on my Ubuntu 15.04, and on my brother's Ubuntu 14.04. Have no idea here, except you can generate it on another machine and copy it on your original machine.

Comment: @AdityaBalwani Try using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` – see if that helps

Comment: Doing `ssh-keygen -t rsa` also generates an ssh2 key.

Comment: @AdityaBalwani I just tested it out and it's working fine for me. I added it to GitHub without problems. If it doesn't work for you, you may try [to convert it](https://burnz.wordpress.com/2007/12/14/ssh-convert-openssh-to-ssh2-and-vise-versa/).

Comment: I figured it out, for some reason i has another ssh-keygen binary in my /usr/local/bin, so when i used it was using that one instead of the one that comes with ubuntu in /usr/bin
Deleting the extra binaries and then reinstalling Openssh-server and openssl fixed everything.
Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaBalwani I added that to answer. Accepting it would be appreciated. Thanks for update!